# Some links from the 2022 Election page point to 2020 resources

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

There's a new election process underway, and, as always, the [2022 Election page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election) is up.

However, half of the links in there point to 2020 resources:

- The first `Election chat room` link points to the [one from 2020](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108464), which cannot be used because it's frozen. Last message posted 602 days ago.
- The `The candidates answer your questions` link also points to the [questionnaire from 2020](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1397).

Please notice that these are the "main" links in the post, and both are outdated.
There is *another* chat room link under *Additional links*, and *another* questionnaire link under *Questionnaire*, both of which look OK. But it is really confusing to have mixed links like that.

Could it be edited to either remove the old links, or put them in a "2020 resources" section at the end of the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a remnant of the previous election system, where those links needed manual updating every time we ran a new election. As you noted, the other links below the fold were correct, as those are generated by the system since our dev team automated a lot of the election process.